# Two jQuery Menus, Open One Close The Other, Never Have Both Open At Same Time

Tags: jquery, search, menu

I have two jquery menus, one a sliding menu for nav and another which is essentially just a search box. The issue I am having is that I want it so that both menus are never simultaneously open at the same time.

Both menus open and close perfectly by clicking their respective buttons. Also when I click anywhere else on the page is closes the open menu(s).

Except - well except when say the nav menu is open and I click on the search button. Or conversely, when I have the search box open and I click on the nav menu button.

Here is the jQuery I have so far...any help is greatly appreciated...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.search').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('.search_area').fadeOut(1);
            $(this).removeClass('active'); }
        else {
        $('.search_area').fadeIn(1);
        $(this).addClass('active'); }
    });
    function closeSearch() {
        $('.search_area').fadeOut(1);
        $('.search').removeClass('active');  
        }
    $(document.body).click( function(e) { closeSearch(); });
    $(".search_area").click( function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
});

var slideMenu = $('.panel');
var slideMenuWidth = $('.panel').width();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.flip').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
            slideMenu.animate({ left: -slideMenuWidth }, 300);              
            $(this).removeClass('open'); }
        else {
            slideMenu.animate({ left: "0px" }, 300);
            $(this).addClass('open'); }
    });
    function closeMenu() {
        slideMenu.animate({ left: -slideMenuWidth }, 300);              
        $('.flip').removeClass('open');  
        }
    $(document.body).click( function(e) { closeMenu(); });
    $(".panel").click( function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
});

</script>
```

[Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmarcello/goyuhekp/)

Comment: Is it possible to setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: I will try...for now you can look at the test site at: http://everymountain.co/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking whether the elements have the class `open` and `active` respectively and call the corresponding function as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.search').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($('.flip').hasClass("open")) closeMenu();
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('.search_area').fadeOut(1);
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.search_area').fadeIn(1);
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });

  function closeSearch() {
    $('.search_area').fadeOut(1);
    $('.search').removeClass('active');
  }

  $(".search_area").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  var slideMenu = $('.panel');
  var slideMenuWidth = $('.panel').width();

  $('.flip').click(function (e) {
    if ($('.search').hasClass("active")) closeSearch();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        slideMenu.animate({
            left: -slideMenuWidth
        }, 300);
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    } else {
        slideMenu.animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 300);
        $(this).addClass('open');
    }
  });

  function closeMenu() {
    slideMenu.animate({
        left: -slideMenuWidth
    }, 300);
    $('.flip').removeClass('open');
  }

  $(document.body).click(function (e) {
    closeMenu();
    closeSearch();
  });

  $(".panel").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goyuhekp/9/)

FYI: You don't need multiple `ready()` handlers...

Comment: It is better very close to fixed...when clicking the menu button it closes the search box and vice-versa. The only thing broken now is when I open the search box with the search button, I either need to click the search button or the menu button to toggle is closed. When I close some where else in the document the search boxstays open.

Comment: @user1447958 Yep, i missed one of your body click handler while posting... http://jsfiddle.net/goyuhekp/9/